# make compiled python project runable cross platform

Tags: python-3.x, linux, windows, pyinstaller, executable

I successfully compile a python project on the `linux` using `PyInstaller`. The project was built using `venv virtual environment`.  The built file can also be successfully run on Linux, for example

```
./predict
```

When I run this executable file on Windows, it will not work, are there anyway to make it runnable cross platform?

Comment: No, both the executable formats and the operating system calls needed to make a program work differ between the two platforms.